# Prevent my website from opening in other mobile apps Web View

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview

When user is using an app, Facebook's app for example and click on my website link, my site will be opened in Facebook's app Webview.
I want to prevent that and open it in a browser instead.
Can I make it work by adding some javascript codes to my website ?

Answer (score 0):

Try window.open() method of Javascript.